# Jasmine - Test method has been called on DOM element from inside Ajax success

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, jasmine

I am completely new to Jasmine and not sure if I am approaching this correctly.  I want to test that the `DataTable()` method is called on my table dom element.  This should occur on successful ajax responses.  However, it is initialized inside an ajax call and I'm not sure how to test this.  The javascript function that makes the ajax call is `updateResults()`.

Here's what I've tried.

```
describe('#ajax', function () {
    var leaderboards, spyOnAjax;
    var formActionUrl = '/jasmine_test_url';

    beforeEach(function () {
        setFixtures('<div class="lb-container">' +
            '<form class="leaderboard" action="' + formActionUrl + '">' +
            '<input type="submit">' +
            '</form>' +
            '<div id="result-box">' +
            '<table class="table-leaderboard"></table> </div>' +
            '</div>');
        leaderboards = new LeaderBoards($('div.lb-container')[0]);
        spyOnAjax = spyOn($, 'ajax').and.callThrough();
        leaderboards.updateResults();
    });

    describe('when updateResults method is called on leaderboards object', function () {

        it('initializes DataTables', function () {
            var table = $('table.table-leaderboard');
            spyOn(table, 'DataTable');
            expect(table.DataTable).toHaveBeenCalled();
        });
    });
});
```

Jasmine tells me that it Expected spy DataTable to have been called.
I don't appear to be getting the table element correctly.  Any advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There are two possibilities that I see:

1. You are adding the spy to the DataTable after the ajax call has already been made.  In general, you should create spies in the `beforeEach` blocks when you are doing other setup.
2. Your ajax call is asynchronous and you need to listen for the call to resolve before the DataTable is created.

In general, though, you should not be making ajax requests in unit tests. All of these tests should be self contained and not rely on external services.